# Unity Debug.Log() Spam

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Whenever I add a debug message to my unity project I get the following message between each line in the output file that is generated.

(Filename: C:/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 64)

Is there any way to turn it off? I have tried using Debug.Log and print.

```
print("Debug Message Here");
```

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the stack trace log type as follows:

```
Application.SetStackTraceLogType(StackTraceLogType.None)
```

For more information, see https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.SetStackTraceLogType.html